# Removing Duplicates from Query Result

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a series of census tables that I am running queries against. Often times the results contain duplicate information, even though not all of the fields are duplicated. Here is some sample data from one of the query outputs:

[image]

Field8 is how I know where my duplicate information is. Even though all the fields are not the same, if Field8 is duplicated, then I only need one of the records. The problem is, the record I need is not always consistent. If the records are duplicate, like they are in the first two records, I only need the record where Field1=162. However when there is no duplicate, like in the last three records, I need all three of those records no matter what Field1 = . So when I can get this query to work correctly, the result will be this:

[image]

Can someone help me write a query to accomplish this?

Comment: can you clarify on which duplicate to pull? in your explanation, _where Field1=162_, is that always the case, when there is a duplicate?

Comment: yes, anytime there is a duplicate in Field8, the record i need to pull will always be where Field1=162.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would something like this work?

```
select b.Field1,b.Field2,b.Field3,b.Field4,b.Field5,b.Field6,b.Field7,b.Field8 from 
(select Field8,max(Field1) as Field1 from census_table group by Field8) a,
census_table b
where b.Field8 = a.Field8
and b.Field1 = a.Field1
```

Comment: sorry it has taken me so long to get back to this. i am testing the results now and will post an update shortly. but so far, it looks like this may work.

Comment: WhiteHat - this worked perfectly. thanks for the quick response and thanks for the help.